# Why jiffies/HZ does not match uptime?

Tags: kernel-parameters, uptime

System uptime is stored in `/proc/uptime`.
As you know, the Linux kernel has a `jiffies` variable which increments by each timer interrupt specified by the `HZ` parameter. I got the value of`HZ` by the following command:

```
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_HZ=

CONFIG_HZ=300
```

In my machine, it's equal to 300. So I divided the `jiffies` given by `/proc/timer_list` by this number.

```
# cat /proc/timer_list | grep -E "^jiffies" | head -n1 && cat /proc/uptime 

jiffies: 4356505571
516409.13 1432145.01
```

I was assumed to get the same number but it's remarkably different.
I mean `4356505571/300=14521685.23` should be really close to `516409.13`, but it's not!

Is there any idea behind `jiffies` that I am not aware of?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130284/discussion-on-question-by-javadr-why-jiffies-hz-does-not-match-uptime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some/many (but not all) modern kernels add an offset to jiffies - it's a very large offset, basically it's `4294967295 - (300 * HZ)`

The `300 * HZ` is a 5 minute offset [so that the kernel always tests jiffy rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612184/10549313)

So, for 300Hz that would be `4294877295`

Subtracting that from the `jiffies` value, then dividing by HZ should produce the right result

```
4356505571 - 4294877295 = 61628276

61628275 / 300 = 205427.587
```

Which STILL doesn't match the values in the question

However, in the comments, the OP says that after 90 seconds, jiffies is 4294904295

```
4294904295 - 4294877295 = 27000

27000 / 300 = 90.000
```

To put that into a simple *formula*

```
uptime = (jiffies - (4294967295 - (300 * HZ))) / HZ
```

or

```
uptime = (jiffies - 4294967295) / HZ - 300
```

---

Note: All my linux systems use the offset - except my OpenWRT routers - despite having kernel version 5.4 in the latest release, the jiffies to uptime relationship is simply as the OP expected:

```
uptime = jiffies / HZ
```

---

Most (all?) of this information was gleaned from

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63176716/10549313 - credit goes to @firo for that; and
- and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612184/10549313 - credit goes to @ZanLynx

However, adding here probably makes sense too